# Ajax / jQuery in Wordpress not running but no error on console

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have code on my page that contains a div. In this div, I want to put the results of a WooCommerce shortcode such as `[products category="slug-of-category"]` when I click a link on the same page. A list of categories (empty links) is to the left of the div. When I click one of these, I want to make an Ajax call to replace the original results in the div with the same shortcode but with the selected category.

---

### in the php file I have the following:

```
<div id="parentCatSlug-<?= $parentslug ?> > 
<ul class="categoryUL">
    <li id='categoryLI-ic-controller-hot-swap-controller''>
    <a id='ic-controller-hot-swap-controller' href="#">Hot Swap Controller</a></li>
    <li id='categoryLI-ic-controller-pfc-controller''>
    <a id='ic-controller-pfc-controller' href="#">PFC Controller</a></li>
    <li id='categoryLI-ic-controller-pol-controller''>
    <a id='ic-controller-pol-controller' href="#">POL Controller</a></li>
</ul></div>

<div id="productBox"> <p>Select a catagory to the left to display the products here.</br></a>
<?php
  echo "<h3>3x5 Openframe Products:</h3>";
  echo do_shortcode ("[products category='ac-dc-power-supply-3-x-5-openframe']"); ?>
</div>
```

---

### in functions.php I have the following:

```
$script = 'http://pmbus.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/PMBus/includes/js/product_shortcode.js';
wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', $script, array ('jquery') ); 
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_product_shortcode', 'show_product_list' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_product_shortcode', 'show_product_list' );
```

---

### in /js/product_shortcode.js I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

jQuery.fn.show_product_list() {
    gciAlert ("in product_shortcode function")
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : ajax-script.ajaxurl,
        data : {
            action: "do_shortcode ('[products "integrated-devices-microcontroller"]')",
            post_id : post_id
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
                var subcat_txt = jQuery(e.target).text()
                jQuery("#productBox").html("<h3>"+subcat_txt+"</h3")
                jQuery("#productBox").html(response)
            }
            else {
                alert("The products could not be listed")
            } // end response
        } // end success:function
    }) // end jQuery.ajax    }) //end jQuery    
    die();
} // end function

}) // end document ready
```

The first problem is that the jQuery.fn.show_product_list() does not fire when I click on one of the links.

The second problem is I am confused if I even have the coding correct for what I want to do. This is my first Ajax/jQuery/WordPress attempt and I have been reading posts and watching videos all week, but just can't seem to put this together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reworking my answer to hopefully explain better and still help.

Also I didn't address your first question about `show_product_list` not firing on click.

I don't see anything in the code you provided that is telling it to fire on click.

Have you tried:

```
jQuery('a').on('click', function(){

    jQuery(this).show_product_list();

});
```

Getting back to the AJAX issue, for *product_shortcode.js* and your AJAX, the way you're passing `"do_shortcode ('[products "integrated-devices-microcontroller"]')"` won't work for two reasons:

1. The string is broken because the double quotes need to be escaped.
2. You can't pass a function and a parameter like that.

Breaking it down, in following bit of code you're sending `action` and `post_id` to *admin-ajax.php*:

```
data : {
   action: "do_shortcode ('[products "integrated-devices-microcontroller"]')",
   post_id: post_id
},
```

*admin-ajax.php* tries to do the action(s) you sent.

From *admin-ajax.php*:

```
if(! has_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] )){....
```

Where *$_REQUEST['action']* is coming from the snippet of code we first talked about `(action: "do_shortcode ('[products "integ.....)`.

With that, Wordpress is looking for action(s) like:

```
'wp_ajax_nopriv_do_shortcode ('[products "integrated-devices-microcontroller"]')' 
'wp_ajax_do_shortcode ('[products "integrated-devices-microcontroller"]')'
```

Which, as you can see, doesn't work out for several reasons.

When defining the hooks `wp_ajax_my_action` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action`, *my_action* is the action you send with your AJAX request.

**In /js/product_shortcode.js**:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

jQuery.fn.show_product_list() {
    gciAlert ("in product_shortcode function")
    var post_id = jQuery(this).data('id');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "post",
        url : ajax-script.ajaxurl,
        data : {
            action: "show_product_list", // This is the action you pass
            post_id : post_id, // This goes along with it
            shortcode: "[your shortcode here]" // You can pass the shortcode

        },
        success: function(response) {

            console.log(response); // See the response

            if(response.type == "success") {
                var subcat_txt = jQuery(e.target).text()
                jQuery("#productBox").html("<h3>"+subcat_txt+"</h3")
                jQuery("#productBox").html(response)
            }
            else {
                alert("The products could not be listed")
            } // end response
        } // end success:function
    }) // end jQuery.ajax    }) //end jQuery    
    die();
} // end function

}) // end document ready
```

**In you functions.php:**

```
$script = 'http://pmbus.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/PMBus/includes/js/product_shortcode.js';
wp_register_script( 'ajax-script', $script, array ('jquery') ); 
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script' );

// When defining the hooks below, I made sure to use show_product_list
// because that is the action we sent.
// Once the action is found, it's executed, and the function show_product_list runs. 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_show_product_list', 'show_product_list' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_show_product_list', 'show_product_list' );

function show_product_list(){
    // Here you can get the shortcode you sent like
    $shortcode = $_POST['shortcode'];

    // Then do the shortcode
    echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
}
```

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: I see. That is starting to make sense, but I am still a bit confused about the functions.php code product_shortcode() { ... } that you added in functions.php, and the ajax function in products_shortcodes.js, where I adjusted the type:"post" code as you recommended. When I run the main php file, I am seeing Undefined fu

Comment: That error is:
Uncaught ReferenceError: product_shortcode is undefined

Comment: I just used product_shortcode as an example function name to illustrate how your Wordpress hooks should look. In the format "wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action" and "wp_ajax_my_action" you'd replace "my_action" with the action being passed from your AJAX. In your original post, it was "do_shortcode...." and in my example I changed it to "product_shortcode" and tried to show how that all needs to match. I'll update my answer with better explanations.

Comment: I am getting closer with your help, and it is starting to make more sense. I have gotten the jQuery to fire and alert me the id of the specific element that I clicked, but still not seeing any response, good or bad, coming from the jQuery.post call to the Ajax.

Comment: Thank you for all the great info. I have fixed most of the issues, but am still not getting the do_shortcode() function to run, or to output anything, via the Ajax call. I have made coding changes so will open a new question with that info.